# github: не могу понять, как collaborator'у склонировать приватный репозиторий

Tags: git, github

Уважаемые господа,

не могу понять, как мне сделать clone приватного репозитория.

История такова:

0. всё делается на машине, на которой я нормально работал со своим репозиторием. То есть - все ключи в .ssh есть, все репозиториии из моего профиля клонируются - коммитятся - пушатся.
1. я вёл проект (private repository) в своём профиле в github
2. Передаю этот репозиторий другому разработчику. Он форкает его, но в своём профиле добавляет меня в коллабораторы на время "переходного периода" - когда мы вместе работаем над проектом.
3. Сейчас в профиле другого разработчика есть форкнутый проект и я добавлен в коллабораторы - см. [image: картинку].
4. при попытке сделать cnone этого репозитория ко мне я получаю требование авторизации, ввожу *свои* логин - пароль в командной строке. Получаю знакомое сообщение о том, что с 13 сентября password authentication was removed (см. [image: картинку])

И вот теперь вопрос: а что мне теперь надо сделать, чтобы я мог работать с репозиторием? Добавить свой публичный ключ в репозиторий другого разработчика я не могу: появляется сообщение "ключ уже используется". А у меня на компе всё хорошо: ключи лежат в .ssh, и я нормально работаю с теми репозиториями, которые "мои" и "в моём профиле гитхаб".

Может, надо добавить *новый* deploy key?

Буду благодарен за советы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь склонировать репозиторий через `https`, в итоге гит понятия не имеет о ваших ключах. Просто замените на клон через `ssh` (в вашем случае это будет что-то вроде `git clone git@github.com:VpushVpull/TEngine-1.git`)

Comment: Точно! Слона то я и не приметил! а я еще думаю - почему мне это окно креденшиал менеджера всплывает.. Спасибо большое, бывают иногда такие "затмения", когда что то делаешь не так, и не замечаешь, что именно!

Comment: @S.H. Бывает такое :)